# Downloading MySQL data based on array format?

Tags: php, mysql

I've setup a MySQL database to to have dates and times of classes, eg:

```
 class  |      class1      |      class2      |       class3       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
physics | Tue@1@Mr. Foobar | Thu@4@Ms. Barfoo | Fri@1@Mr. Bobsmith |
math    | Mon@4@Ms. Foobar | Tue@3@Ms. Barfoo | Fri@2@Mr. Lala     |
cs      | Tue@2@Mr. Foobar | Fri@4@Ms. Barfoo |                    |
```

Basically, it's array formatted values in a database, which I planned on explode()-ing when required, but I didn't realize I'd have to do more fine grained searches.

The array format is `Day@Period@Teacher`

For example, if today were Tuesday, how would you suggest I get all of Tuesday's classes in order, such as this:

```
Today's Classes
1. Physics
2. CS
3. Math
```

Or should I just give up and separate out `class1` in to `class1day`, `class1period`, `class1teacher` ?

My best idea is something along the lines of:

```
$date = $date("l");
mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM classes 
WHERE class1 OR class2 OR class3
LIKE '$date%' ORDER BY //(I have no clue what to order by)
");
```

Cheers,
any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Also, you may want to rethink your database strategy.

Comment: Normalize your database.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using following query.

```
SELECT class 
FROM   table tbl1 
WHERE  Substring(class1, 1, 3) = 'Tue' 
        OR Substring(class2, 1, 3) = 'Tue' 
        OR Substring(class3, 1, 3) = 'Tue'
```

But You should normalize your database. which will make it easier to search and reduce data redundancy.

Comment: Really pay attention to the last sentence of this answer : "But You should normalize your database. which will make it easier to search and reduce data redundancy."